# jquery details tag alternative

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a simple jquery solution that does the same drop down function as the html5 details tag? I have looked at some plugins but they all seem buggy with ie. I think it may be best to just do it with jquery for now?

html5 way (but this does not work in ie)

```
<details>
  <summary>Details Summary</summary>
  <p>Pellentesque aliquet lacinia libero id sodales. Curabitur nibh velit, varius in semper ac, suscipit quis magna. Phasellus faucibus venenatis leo ut convallis. Maecenas tempus risus id nibh iaculis vehicula. Aenean vel quam lorem, et sagittis velit. Nullam a ligula lectus, at iaculis mauris. Mauris id tempus dolor. </p>
</details>
```

jquery way?

Comment: That does at least display the content in IE, correct? so all you'd have to do is detect whether or not the browser supports the details tag, and if it doesn't, hide the paragraph tag, then show it when appropriate. No need for a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
<details>
  <summary>Details Summary</summary>
  <p>Pellentesque aliquet lacinia libero...</p>
</details>
```

OR

```
<div class="details">
  <div class="summary">Details Summary</div>
  <p>Pellentesque aliquet lacinia libero...</p>
</div>
```

**adjust below code accordingly**

```
details > p{display:none;}

$('body').on('click', 'details summary',function() { $(this).find('p').toggle(); });
```